# How I can read more than 16384 bytes using OpenSSL TLS?

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to read a big chunk of data using OpenSSL TLS sockets, and I'm always stuck at 16384 being read. How I can read more?

```
SSL_CTX* ctx;
int server;
SSL* ssl;
int bytes;
std::string result;
std::vector<char> buffer(999999999);

ctx = InitCTX();
server = OpenConnection();
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);
if (SSL_connect(ssl) != -1)
{
    std::string msg = 0; //request here
    SSL_write(ssl, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, &buffer[0], buffer.size());
}

result.append(buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend());
```

Comment: Call SSL_read again...

Comment: @rustyx how I should determine if I've read everything?

Comment: @qwerty123456 TCP is a byte stream. Whether you use TLS or not, there are only 2 ways to know when to stop reading: 1) if you know beforehand how much data you are expecting, then you keep reading for exactly that many bytes. 2) If the data is delimited, then you keep reading until you encounter the delimiter.

Comment: @qwerty123456 also, your use of `buffer` iterators is wrong. You are appending the entire `buffer` to `result` even if you did not actually fill up the `buffer` to its max capacity. The read tells you how many bytes were actually put into the `buffer`, so do not append more than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TLS protocol encapsulates data in [records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_record) that are individually encrypted and authenticated. Records have a maximum payload of 16 kB (minus a few bytes), and [`SSL_read()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_read.html) will only process one record at a time.

I suggest you change the size of `buffer` to 16384 bytes to match. Note that allocating ~1 GB as you did is way too much anyway, as that amount of memory would then potentially not be available to other processes.

Then, as rustyx mentioned in the comments, just read more in a loop. If the other side can respond with multiple records, it would be good if it would somehow send the size of the response in the first record, so you would know how much to read.